# VC++/MFC メモリDCの破棄時に不正終了してしまう場合がある (その２)

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

以前、リサイズ可能なメモリDCでの不正終了について質問をしました。

[VC++/MFC メモリDCの破棄時に不正終了してしまう場合がある](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/83416)

申し訳ありません、登録したばかりで慣れておりません。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

①不正終了 DeleteMemDC()箇所 : map情報から
②画面は5枚でなく2枚です。
③ワーカースレッドにてメモリDCに再描画
④OnPaint()にてスクリーンに転送してます。

**質問1**
DeleteMemDC()にてハンドルがNULLでもAPIを実行してしまうので、NULL以外で実行するようにした方が良いのでしょうか？

**質問2**
イベントビューアーでの終了レポートとVC++ map情報からDeleteMemDC()内で落ちているようですが、何が原因かまでは記録されません。
こういった時調べる手立てとしてどのような施策ができるのか、ご指導いただければ幸いです。

以下がソースコードの抜粋になります。

```cpp
#define WM_USER_UPDATE_GRAPH    (WM_USER + 3)

CRITICAL_SECTION csm;

enum eLayer {
  L_Graph = 0,
  L_Splash,
  L_Max_Count,
};

// CFooDlg ダイアログ
class CFooDlg : public CDialog
{

  HANDLE hStartRedrawThread;
  HANDLE hKillRedrawThread;

  HANDLE hRedrawThreadStarted;
  HANDLE hRedrawThreadKilled;

  CWinThread* m_pRedrawThread;

  CStatic m_graphTemp;              //ダイアログ上のグラフ描画域

};


CFooDlg::CFooDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
  : CDialog(CFooDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
  m_bSplash = TRUE;
  m_bResized = FALSE;
    :
  m_pRedrawThread = NULL;

  InitializeCriticalSection(&csm);


}

CFooDlg::~CFooDlg()
{
   :
  DeleteCriticalSection(&csm);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CFooDlg, CDialog)
{
:
  ON_MESSAGE(WM_USER_REDRAW, &CFooDlg::OnUserRedraw)
:

}

BOOL CFooDlg::OnInitDialog()
{

  CDialog::OnInitDialog();

  // "バージョン情報..." メニューをシステム メニューに追加します。

  // IDM_ABOUTBOX は、システム コマンドの範囲内になければなりません。
  ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
  ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

  g_hWnd = this->m_hWnd;
  SetHook();


  CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
  if (pSysMenu != NULL) {
    BOOL bNameValid;
    CString strAboutMenu;
    bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty()) {
      pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
      pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
    }
  }

  // このダイアログのアイコンを設定します。アプリケーションのメイン ウィンドウがダイアログでない場合、
  //  Framework は、この設定を自動的に行います。
  SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);           // 大きいアイコンの設定
  SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);      // 小さいアイコンの設定

  char vbuf[128];
  // タイトルバー表示(リソースより版数情報)
  CString ver = APP->GetVersionString();
  CString title;
  GetWindowText(title);

  RecalcLayout();

  CRect rect;
  m_graphTemp.GetClientRect(&rect);

  CDC* pDC = m_graphTemp.GetDC();

  for(int i=0;i<L_Max_Count;i++) {
    BOOL r = m_memDC[i].CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    r = m_bmp[i].CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC,rect.Width(),rect.Height());
    m_pOldBmp[i] = m_memDC[i].SelectObject(&m_bmp[i]);
    dbg_printf("OnInitDialog::m_pOldBmp[%d] = %p\n", i, m_pOldBmp[i]);
    m_memDC[i].BitBlt(0,0,rect.Width(),rect.Height(),NULL,-1,-1,WHITENESS);
  }

  m_graphTemp.ReleaseDC(pDC);

//  m_bSplash = TRUE;
  m_bSplash = ::GetPrivateProfileInt("Display", "Show_Splash",1,APP->GetIniPath());
  :
  :
  hRedrawThreadStarted = CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL);
  hRedrawThreadKilled = CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL);

  if(m_pRedrawThread ==NULL) {
    m_pRedrawThread = AfxBeginThread(Redraw_Thread, this);
    m_pRedrawThread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
  } else {
    AfxMessageBox("プログラム起動時に問題が発生しました。");
    DestroyWindow();
    return FALSE;
  }
  SetEvent(hStartRedrawThread);
  if(WaitForSingleObject(hRedrawThreadStarted,5000L)==WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
    AfxMessageBox("画面更新スレッドが起動できませんでした");
    DestroyWindow();
    return FALSE;
  }

}

BOOL CFooDlg::DestroyWindow()
{
  // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
  ::EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)this );

  PlaySound(NULL, NULL, 0);

  UnHook(); 

  ReleaseCapture();

  for(int i=0;i<L_Max_Count;i++) {
    dbg_printf("m_pOldBmp[%d] = %p\n", i, m_pOldBmp[i]); //V1_6_8(408)
    m_memDC[i].SelectObject(m_pOldBmp[i]);
    m_bmp[i].DeleteObject();
    m_memDC[i].DeleteDC();
  }


  if(m_pRedrawThread) {
    SetEvent(hKillRedrawThread);
    Sleep(100L);
    WaitForSingleObject( m_pRedrawThread->m_hThread , INFINITE );
    delete m_pRedrawThread;
  }

//  PostQuitMessage();

///  m_Graph.DestroyWindow();
  Sleep(500L);

  DeleteCriticalSection(&H8Ctl::cs);

  Sleep(50L);

  return CDialog::DestroyWindow();
}

void CFooDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
  CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

  // TODO: Add your message handler code here

  AdjustLayout();

  // For Statusbar
  RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0);

  m_bResized = TRUE;


}

void CFooDlg::OnPaint()
{
  DWORD t = GetTickCount();


  if (IsIconic())
  {
    CPaintDC dc(this); // 描画のデバイス コンテキスト

    SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

    // クライアントの四角形領域内の中央
    int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
    int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
    int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

    // アイコンの描画
    dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
  }
  else
  {

    DWORD tic = GetTickCount();

   if(!m_bSplash && m_bResized) {  //起動時のスプラッシュ表示までは、メモリＤＣをリサイズしない
     dbg_printf("resized\n");
     EnterCriticalSection(&csm);
     DeleteMemDC();
     CreateMemDC();
     LeaveCriticalSection(&csm);
     m_bResized = FALSE;

   }

    CRect rect;
    m_graphTemp.GetClientRect(&rect);

    CDC* pDC = m_graphTemp.GetDC();

    if(m_bSplash)
      pDC->BitBlt(0,0,rect.right,rect.bottom,&m_memDC[L_Splash],0,0,SRCCOPY);
    else
    {
      pDC->BitBlt(0,0,rect.right,rect.bottom,&m_memDC[L_Graph],0,0,SRCCOPY);
      ers_t = -1;

    }

    m_graphTemp.ReleaseDC(pDC);

    CDialog::OnPaint();

  }

}

// ユーザーメッセージハンドラ
// ｸﾞﾗﾌをメモリDCに描画する
LRESULT CFootDlg::OnUserUpdateChild(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  DWORD t = GetTickCount();

  CRect rect;
  m_graphTemp.GetClientRect(&rect);
  drawGraph(&m_memDC[L_Graph],rect.Width(),rect.Height(),0,rect.Height());

  BYTE pv[20];
  memset(pv,0x00,sizeof(pv));
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    pv[i] = H8Ctl::pv.vent_PV[i];
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    pv[i+4] = H8Ctl::pv.curt_PV[i];

  if(pDispDlg)
    pDispDlg->UpdateLED(m_lamp, pv);

  if (pMainGraphSetupDlg)
  {
    if (!m_bCursor && !bLogvw /* == isToday()*/)
    {
      CTime today = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
      cur_t = today.GetHour() * 60 + today.GetMinute();
    }
    pMainGraphSetupDlg->m_DlgBar.UpdateCurrentValue(cur_t, bLogvw);
  }

  return 1L;
}

// *memDCにグラフを描画
void CFooTestDlg::drawGraph(CDC* pDC, int devWidth, int devHeight,int vwOrgX,int vwOrgY, BOOL bPrint) 
{

  COLORREF col = DK_GREEN;

  CFont font,fontS;
  CFont* pOldFont;

  font.CreatePointFont(160,"MS UI Gothic");
  fontS.CreatePointFont(120,"MS UI Gothic");

  CRect rcw;
  CRect rect;
  m_graphTemp.GetClientRect(&rect);

  int map = pDC->SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);//通常座標系

  CPoint ptOrg = CPoint(-LP_MX, -LP_MY);         // 原点
  CSize  szWind = CSize(LP_W, LP_H);         // 仮想ウィンドウサイズ

  CSize szW = pDC->SetWindowExt(szWind);  //仮想ウィンドウサイズ
  CPoint ptW = pDC->SetWindowOrg(ptOrg);

  CSize szV = pDC->SetViewportExt(devWidth, -devHeight);
  CPoint ptV = pDC->SetViewportOrg(vwOrgX, vwOrgY);
  CBrush* pOldBrsh = (CBrush*)pDC->SelectStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);

  COLORREF bk = pDC->GetBkColor();
  pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);  // 背景透明

  pOldFont = pDC->SelectObject(&font);

  bk = RGB(255,255,255);
  rcw = CRect(ptOrg.x,ptOrg.y,ptOrg.x+szWind.cx,ptOrg.y+szWind.cy);

  pDC->FillSolidRect(&rcw, RGB(255,255,255));

  CPen pen(PS_DOT,0,LT_GRAY);  //目盛
  CPen pen0(PS_SOLID,0,BLACK);  //目盛
  CPen penTh(PS_SOLID,0,LT_GRAY);
  CPen penB(PS_SOLID,3,BLACK);
  CPen penBold(PS_SOLID,5,GRAY);  //目盛

  CPen penT(PS_SOLID,1,col);
  CPen px(PS_SOLID,1,RGB(192,128,192));
  CPen penXX(PS_SOLID,1,RGB(0,0,255));
  CPen penXXX(PS_DOT,0,RGB(0,0,192));

  CRgn rgnG;
  CBrush brshS(RGB(255,255,192));  // 昼時間

  int w = LP_X;
  int hh = LP_Y;

  int rise = suntime[0]/100 * 60 + suntime[0]%100;
  int set = suntime[1]/100 * 60 + suntime[1]%100;
  int south = (set - rise) / 2 + rise;
  if(bLogvw) {
    rise = vLog_suntime[0]/100 * 60 + vLog_suntime[0]%100;
    set = vLog_suntime[1]/100 * 60 + vLog_suntime[1]%100;
    south = (set - rise) / 2 + rise;
  }
  ////// 昼時間の描画
  float xx = (float)LP_X/(float)(Tick[1] - Tick[0]);  // スケールX

  int   rr = (int)((rise-Tick[0]) * xx);
  int   ss = (int)((set -Tick[0]) * xx);

  // グラフ域のみに描画制限
  CRect rcGrp(0,0,LP_X,LP_Y); //LP領域
  pDC->LPtoDP(&rcGrp);
  rgnG.CreateRectRgn(rcGrp.left,rcGrp.top,rcGrp.right,rcGrp.bottom);

  CRect rc(rr,0,ss,hh);
  pDC->FillRect(rc, &brshS);

  // 全面に制限変更

  CString str;
  int wh = w/24;

  CPen* pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject(&penB);

  // 時間軸描画
  int x;
  // 段階ズームおよび開始分(!=0)対応
  pDC->SelectObject(&penB);     // THIN_SOLID
  x = (int)(0);
  pDC->MoveTo(x, 0);  pDC->LineTo(x,hh);
  x = (int)(((float)(Tick[1]- Tick[0]) * xx)+0.5f);
  pDC->MoveTo(x, 0);  pDC->LineTo(x,hh);

  for(int i=Tick[0];i<=Tick[1];i++) {
    if(!(i%180)) { //3時間
      x = (int)(((float)(i-Tick[0]) * xx)+0.5f);

      if(m_swTimeScale) {
        if(!(i%360))
          pDC->SelectObject(&penTh);  //Thin_SOLID
        else
          pDC->SelectObject(&pen);  //DOT

        pDC->MoveTo(x, 0);  pDC->LineTo(x, hh);
      }

      pDC->SelectObject(&penB);
      pDC->MoveTo(x, -hh/100);  pDC->LineTo(x,hh/100);
    } else if(!(i%60)) { //1時間
      x = (int)(((float)(i-Tick[0]) * xx)+0.5f);
      pDC->SelectObject(&pen0);
      pDC->MoveTo(x, -hh/200);  pDC->LineTo(x,hh/200);
    }
    if(!(i%60)) { //1時間
      str.Format("%02d",i/60); 
      CSize sz = pDC->GetTextExtent(str);
      pDC->TextOut(x-sz.cx/2,-20,str);
    }
  }
  float temp = 0.f;       //開始温度
  //m_nUnit : コンボボックスでの選択番号
  // =>tGraphRangeより選択番号を使って、MeasTypeを得る
  // =>得たmeastypeより、gInfoを参照して、単位、範囲などを得る.
  CSize szT;
  str = _T("XXXX");
  szT = pDC->GetTextExtent(str);

  MeasureValue mt = (MeasureValue)m_nUnit[0];
  tGraphConfig* p = getMainGraphConfig(mt);
  if(p!=NULL) {
    temp = p->min;

    // 温度軸(縦軸)描画
    float r = p->max - p->min;
    float yy = ((temp-p->min)  * hh)/r;

    pDC->SetTextColor(p->col);
    if(p->step) { // 0除算対策
      DWORD t = GetTickCount();    
      pDC->SelectObject(&pen);
      for(int i=(int)(p->min);i<=(int)(p->max);i+=(int)(p->step)){
        if(GetTickCount() - t > 100L)
          break;
        temp = (float)i;
        yy = ((temp-p->min)* hh)/r;

      if(m_swItemScale) {
        if(i==0)
          pDC->SelectObject(&penTh);  //THIN_SOLID
        else
          pDC->SelectObject(&pen);  //DOT

        pDC->MoveTo(0, (int)(yy+0.5f)); pDC->LineTo(LP_X,(int)(yy+0.5f));
      }

        pDC->MoveTo(-LP_X/200, (int)(yy+0.5f)); pDC->LineTo(LP_X/200,(int)(yy+0.5f));


        str.Format(" %3hd ", (short)temp); // 前後空白マージン
        if(p->mt == MV_None) {
          str.Format(" %u ", (UINT)temp); // 状況は符号なし
        }
        CSize szText = pDC->GetTextExtent(str);
        CPoint pt = CPoint(-szText.cx, (int)(yy+szText.cy/2));
        CRect rect(pt,CSize(szText.cx, (int)(-szText.cy)));
        //pDC->Rectangle(rect);
        if(p->mt != MV_None)
          pDC->DrawText(str,rect,DT_SINGLELINE | DT_RIGHT);
      }
    }

    yy = ((p->max-p->min)* hh)/r;

    szT = pDC->GetTextExtent("00%%");
    str.Format("%s %s", p->name, p->unit);  // name追加
    pDC->TextOut(-szT.cx,(int)yy+szT.cy*3/2, str);
  }

  pDC->SelectObject(&penB);     // THIN_SOLID
  pDC->MoveTo(0,    0);
  pDC->LineTo(1440, 0);
  pDC->LineTo(LP_X, 0);

  //右軸
  mt = (MeasureValue)m_nUnit[1];
  p = getMainGraphConfig(mt);
  if(p!=NULL) {
    temp = p->min;

    // 温度軸(縦軸)描画
    float r = p->max - p->min;
    float yy = ((temp-p->min)  * hh)/r;

    pDC->SetTextColor(p->col);


    r = p->max - p->min;
    DWORD t = GetTickCount();
    for(int i=(int)(p->min);i<=(int)(p->max);i+=(int)(p->step)){
      if(GetTickCount() - t > 100L)
        break;
      temp = (float)i;
      yy = ((temp-p->min)  * hh)/r;

      str.Format(" %3hd ", (short)temp); // 前後空白はマージン
      if(p->mt == MV_None) {
        str.Format(" %u ", (UINT)temp); // 状況は符号なし
      }
      CSize szText = pDC->GetTextExtent(str);
      CPoint pt = CPoint(LP_X, (int)(yy+szText.cy/2));
      CRect rect(pt,CSize(szText.cx,-szText.cy));
      //pDC->Rectangle(rect);
      pDC->DrawText(str,rect,DT_SINGLELINE | DT_RIGHT);

    }
    
    yy = ((p->max-p->min)* hh)/r;
    
    szT = pDC->GetTextExtent("00%%");
    str.Format("%s %s", p->name, p->unit);  // name追加
    pDC->TextOut(LP_X-szT.cx, (int)(yy+szT.cy*3/2), str);
  }

  int h = m_u8time[4];
  int m = m_u8time[5];
  int x0 = h * wh;
  int xo = wh * m / 60;
  int tick = (h*60 + m)%TIME_RANGE;


  int   tic = (int)( (tick-Tick[0]) * xx );

  ////////////////////
  // グラフ、目標温度をスケール内での描画に制限
  pDC->SelectClipRgn(&rgnG);

  // 設定1 or 設定2の　換気・暖房ライン(時間帯設定ライン)
  // 換気設定
  // 冷房設定
  // 暖房管理1
  // 暖房管理2 の設定ラインの描画
  if(!bLogvw) {
    if(m_swKankiSV[0])
      DrawSV(pDC, Kanki_Temp,   timz[0], timz_N, 1440, hh );
    if(m_swHeatSV[0])
      DrawSV(pDC, Danbo_Temp_1, timz_h[0], timz_N, 1440, hh );
    if(m_swHeatSV[1])
      DrawSV(pDC, Danbo_Temp_2, timz_h[1], timz_N, 1440, hh );
  }

  pDC->SelectClipRgn(NULL);
  ////////////////////
  // クライアント座標(物理座標DP)
  // 以下の描画時、グラフ域外に項目名を書くため
  CFont* pF = pDC->SelectObject(&fontS);
  for(int b = 0; b < 16; b ++) {
    DrawStatusGraph(pDC, 1<<b, tick, LP_X, hh);
  }
  pDC->SelectObject(pF);
  pDC->SelectClipRgn(&rgnG);
  // グラフ描画 (gccでのmkr!=0の時のみ表示する。)
  for(int i=1;i<MV_Max_Count;i++) {
    MeasureValue mt = gcc[i].mt;
    if(mt == MV_Invalid_Item)
      break;
    if(mt < MV_None || mt >= MV_Max_Count)
      continue;
    DrawMeasGraph(pDC, mt, tick,  LP_X, hh);
  }


  if(Pressed) {
    CPoint mk[4];
    mk[0] = ptSelectDP[0];
    mk[1] = CPoint(ptSelectDP[0].x, ptSelectDP[1].y);
    mk[2] = ptSelectDP[1];
    mk[3] = CPoint(ptSelectDP[1].x, ptSelectDP[0].y);
    pDC->SelectObject(penXX);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
      pDC->DPtoLP(&mk[i]);
      pDC->FillSolidRect(CRect(mk[i].x-10,mk[i].y-10,mk[i].x+10,mk[i].y+10),RGB(0,0,255));
    }
    CRect rcLP = CRect(ptSelectDP[0],ptSelectDP[1]);
    pDC->DPtoLP(&rcLP);
    pDC->SelectObject(&penXXX);
    pDC->SelectStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    pDC->Rectangle(&rcLP);
  }


  pDC->SelectObject(pOldFont);
  pDC->SelectObject(pOldBrsh);
  pDC->SelectObject(pOldPen);
  pDC->SelectClipRgn( NULL ); 

  pDC->SetMapMode(map);//通常座標系
  pDC->SetWindowExt(szW);
  pDC->SetViewportExt(szV);

  pDC->SetWindowOrg(ptW);
  pDC->SetViewportOrg(ptV);

  pDC->SelectClipRgn(NULL);

  brshS.DeleteObject(); //B1.3 Added

  pen.DeleteObject();
  pen0.DeleteObject();
  penTh.DeleteObject();
  penB.DeleteObject();
  penBold.DeleteObject();

  penT.DeleteObject();
  px.DeleteObject();
  penXX.DeleteObject();
  penXXX.DeleteObject();

  rgnG.DeleteObject();

  fontS.DeleteObject();
  font.DeleteObject();

}


UINT Redraw_Thread(LPVOID ptr)
{
  CFooDlg* p = (CFooDlg*)ptr;
  HWND hWnd =p->m_hWnd;

  DWORD tick = GetTickCount();
  DWORD tick2 = GetTickCount();
  DWORD tick3 = GetTickCount();
  UINT ret = 0;
int th = 0;

  SetEvent(p->hRedrawThreadStarted);
  dbg_printf("****Redraw_Thread Started****\n");

  MSG message;

  while(1) {
    if(::PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){ 
      //ループ中のマウスメッセージ処理
      ::TranslateMessage(&message);
      ::DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    Sleep(50L);
    if(WaitForSingleObject(p->hKillRedrawThread, 100L) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
      break;
    if(WaitForSingleObject(p->hStartRedrawThread, 100L) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
      continue;

    EnterCriticalSection(&csm);
    if((GetTickCount() - tick) > 500L) {
      tick = GetTickCount();
      ::PostMessage(hWnd,WM_USER_REDRAW, NULL, 0L);
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&csm);

  }
  SetEvent(p->hRedrawThreadKilled);
  dbg_printf("****Ended Redraw_Thread****\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: stackoverflow 的には元質問の編集をしてほしかったところです。あとこれでは完全にデバッグ依頼であって質問ではないのですが・・・

Answer (score 0):

とりあえず下記サイトを参考に、アプリ クラッシュ時のプロセス ダンプを採取する設定を行い、問題現象再現後に生成されたプロセス ダンプを解析してみては?

Windowsエラー報告（WER）機能を使ってアプリケーションのクラッシュダンプ（ユーザーダンプ）を作成する方法
https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX119302

Comment: お世話になります。
ご指導ありがとうございます。
かなり難しそうですが、調べて試してみたいです。 このアプリですが、稼働し続けての使用状況となり、
発生しないPC環境もあるのですが、発生する場合は、月に2～3回
頻発することもあります。

Comment: レジストリの設定しておけば、クラッシュ時に自動でプロセス ダンプを生成してくれるので、ダンプさえ取得できれば、後からでも調べることができます。
それ以外の調査方法としては、Microsoft Store から "WinDbg Preview" デバッガをインストールし、そのデバッガ以上から該当アプリを起動させておけば、クラッシュの原因につながるエラーが発生した時点でデバッガにブレークインするはずなので、その時のコール スタック等の状態を確認すれば、より詳しい調査が出来ると思います。